# Writing contents of makefile (>131000 chars) variable to a file?

Tags: makefile

How can I write the contents of a makefile variable to file, without invoking a shell command?
The problem is that the contents of the variable is possible longer than the shell allows for a command (i.e. longer than MAX_ARG_STRLEN (131072) characters).

In particular, in a makefile I have a variable containing a long list of filenames to process (including their absolute pathes for out-of-source builds). Now I need to write those filenames to a (temporary) file, which I can then pass to another command.

So far, we had a rule like (`$COLLATED_FILES` is the variable containing the paths):

```
$(outdir)/collated-files.tely: $(COLLATED_FILES)
    $(LYS_TO_TELY) --name=$(outdir)/collated-files.tely --title="$(TITLE)" \
    --author="$(AUTHOR)" $^
```

This breaks if `COLLATED_FILES` is longer than about 130000 characters, we get the error message:

```
make[2]: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
```

As a solution, we are now trying to write the contents of the variable to a file and use that file in the `$(LYS_TO_TELY)` command. Unfortunately, I have not yet found a way to do this without invoking the shell. 
My attempts include:

```
$(outdir)/collated-files.list: $(COLLATED_FILES)
    echo "" > $@
    $(foreach f,$^,echo $f >> $@;)
```

But this also invokes all `echo` commands at once in a shell, so the shell command is just as long.

Is there any way to write the contents of `$(COLLATED_FILES)` to a file on disk without passing them on the command line to a shell command?

I also searched whether I could pipe the contents of the variable to the shell, but I couldn't find anything in that direction, either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using GNU Make, there is the `file` function!

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html

```
$(file op filename,text)
```

where `op` is either `>` or `>>`.

This requires GNU Make 4.0+

Answer (score 2):

You could move whatever makefile code you use to build up the value of `COLLATED_FILES` to a trivial helper makefile, then invoke make recursively from your original makefile and use trivial shell redirection to capture the stdout of the recursive make invocation -- basically using make as a rudimentary text-processing tool in that context.  For example, create a makefile called `get_collated_files.mk` with these contents:

```
COLLATED_FILES=abc
COLLATED_FILES+=def
COLLATED_FILES+=ghi
# ... etc ...

# Use $(info) to print the list to stdout.  If you want each filename on a 
# separate line, use this instead:
#
# $(foreach name,$(COLLATED_FILES),$(info $(name)))

$(info $(COLLATED_FILES))

all: ;@#shell no-op to quell make complaints
```

Then, in your original makefile:

```
collated-files.list:
        $(MAKE) -f get_collated_files.mk > $@

$(outdir)/collated-files.tely: collated-files.list
    $(LYS_TO_TELY) --name=$(outdir)/collated-files.tely --title="$(TITLE)" \
    --author="$(AUTHOR)" --filelist=collated-files.list
```

This will be quite a lot more efficient than using hundreds or thousands of individual `echo` invocations to append to the file one path at a time.

**EDIT**:  One final option, if you really want to have each filename on a separate line, and you have a lot of control over how `COLLATED_FILES` is defined:

```
define NL


endef
COLLATED_FILES=abc
COLLATED_FILES+=$(NL)def
COLLATED_FILES+=$(NL)ghi
$(info $(COLLATED_FILES))
all: ;@#no-op
```

This approach allows you to again use just one call to `$(info)`, if that's important to you for some reason.

Comment: That's a good idea, but we still need a way to put each filename on a separate line...

Comment: @Beta: I don't see in the OP any requirement that the filenames be on separate lines, but I'll amend my answer to include that variant as well.

Comment: Well, I inferred it from the trouble ho took to write it that way (and not just `echo $^ > $@`). Your second solution works, but with thousands of `info` commands it loses the elegance of your first solution. I've been looking for a clean way to get the newlines into the variable, but I haven't found one. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Beta: thousands of `info` commands is still quit a lot more efficient than running `echo` thousands of `times.  There is one more strategy though, I'll amend my answer to include that as well.

Comment: [*facepalm*] Nice. The direct approach.

Comment: Got a quick question about this approach because I don't know what exactly to search for but is there a limitation on how big of a variable you can export with windows? I have read that user defined variables cant be longer than 32k which really isn't too big if you have a fairly long list of path + files

Comment: @ThePosey: check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @EricMelski "Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The maximum size of the environment block for the process is 32,767 characters. Starting with Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, there is no technical limitation on the size of the environment block." thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a patch to gnu make that lets you directly write a variable into a file. It creates a new 'writefile' function, similar to the existing 'info' function, except it takes a filename argument and writes to the file:

https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?35384

Comment: Since 2012-01-29, the **[$(file op filename,text)](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html)** function is part of GNU make. Available in all releases after 3.82.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you should rethink your build design-- surely there's a better way than letting a variable get this big. But here's a way to do it:

```
# Make sure this doesn't collide with any of your other targets.    
NAMES_TO_WRITE = $(addprefix write_,$(COLLATED_FILES)) 

collated-files.list: $(NAMES_TO_WRITE)

write_blank:
        echo "" > collated-files.list

.PHONY: $(NAMES_TO_WRITE)
$(NAMES_TO_WRITE) : write_% : write_blank
        echo $* >> collated-files.list
```